# Vercel - choose Go version

Tags: go, version, vercel, jamstack

I'm trying to use Go 1.17 for my serverless functions on Vercel. When I'm deploying, I get this message :

> Warning: Unknown Go version in /vercel/path1/go.mod

So I would like to know if there is a maximum supported version of Go for serverless functions.

Comment: Does your go.mod have a version number in it? Can you add your `go.mod` to the question? Or at least the top of the `go.mod` that has the version number?

Comment: It seems like Vercel supports Go v1.16 max: https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/go/go-version

Answer (score 0):

Posting Andrey's comment as an official answer so that it is more obvious.  He is correct that there is a maximum Go version that the Vercel Go Runtime supports.  As of March 8th 2024, that version is Go 1.20.

See the [Go Version](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/runtimes/go#go-version) section of the **Using the Go Runtime with Serverless Functions** documentation.